# When decoding a message with Circe, is it possible to extract the invalid value from a DecodingFailure

Tags: scala, circe

When attempting to decode a json message with circe, I have a requirement to return the original value that caused the decoding failure, if possible.

As an example, I receive some `invalidJson` that contains an `invalidUuid`. Having access to both the `invalidJson` and the `history: List[CursorOp]`, how would I grab the `invalidValue`?

Some sample code, illustrating the problem:

````scala
import java.util.UUID

import io.circe.{CursorOp, DecodingFailure}
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}
import cats.implicits._
import io.circe.generic.auto._

class JsonSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  case class TestDecode(test: Test)
  case class Test(uuidKey: Option[UUID])

  "a token decoder" should "return the invalid value for a decoding failure" in {
    val invalidUuid = "invalid"
    val invalidJson = s"""{"test": {"uuidKey": "$invalidUuid"}}"""

    io.circe.parser.decode[TestDecode](invalidJson) match {
      case Left(DecodingFailure(_, history)) =>
        getInvalidValue(invalidJson, history) shouldEqual invalidUuid.some
      case Left(_) => fail("should have returned a DecodingFailure")
      case Right(_) => fail("should have returned a DecodingFailure")

    }

    def getInvalidValue(invalidJson: String, history: List[CursorOp]): Option[String] = ???
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is exactly the kind of use case that `replay` is designed to support:

```
import io.circe.{CursorOp, Decoder, DecodingFailure}
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.jawn.parse
import java.util.UUID

case class TestDecode(test: Test)
case class Test(uuidKey: Option[UUID])

val Right(doc) = parse("""{"test": {"uuidKey": "invalid"}}""")
val Left(DecodingFailure(_, ops)) = Decoder[TestDecode].decodeJson(doc)

doc.hcursor.replay(ops).focus
// res0: Option[io.circe.Json] = Some("invalid")
```

It's a method on `ACursor` that takes a list of operations and applies them to the cursor (in reverse order, since the operations are generally gathered as a stack but in this case we want FIFO).

Note that the `focus` is an `Option` because the library doesn't have any static guarantee that you're applying this list of operations to the same JSON value you initially tried to decode, so it could fail.